# How to download a file of which the download button brings up a pop-up with a scraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to download APKs from sites such as https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-12-19-56-release/youtube-12-19-56-android-apk-download/. When you click the "Download APK" button, in Tor Browser it brings up a pop-up window giving you the choice to open or save the file (see below).

[image]

I would like to save the file.

So far, I've tried getting this to work with Scrapy using the following spider:

```
import scrapy
from apkmirror.items import ApkmirrorItem

class ApkmirrorScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "apkmirror-scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["apkmirror.com"]
    # start_urls = ['https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-12-19-56-release/youtube-12-19-56-android-apk-download/']

    custom_settings = {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-12-19-56-release/youtube-12-19-56-android-apk-download/']
        for url in urls:
            request = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['proxy'] = "http://localhost:8118"
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = ApkmirrorItem()

        icon_relative_link = response.css('.siteTitleBar').xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first()
        icon_link = response.urljoin(icon_relative_link)
        item['image_urls'] = [icon_link]

        download_relative_link = response.css('.downloadButton').xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
        download_link = response.urljoin(download_relative_link)
        item['file_urls'] = [download_link]

        yield item
```

where I have the [rdsubhas/tor-privoxy](https://github.com/rdsubhas/docker-tor-privoxy-alpine) container running in the background to ensure anonymity. (The spider should also work without a proxy if you comment out the `'proxy'` line in `start_requests`, or comment in the `start_urls` line and comment out the entire `start_requests` method).

In `items.py` I've included the required fields in accordance with https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html:

```
import scrapy

class ApkmirrorItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
```

and in `settings.py` I've enabled the pipelines as follows:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1
}

IMAGES_STORE = '/tmp/apkmirror_test/images'
FILES_STORE = '/tmp/apkmirror_test/files'
```

The problem is that the file downloading doesn't work. After I `scrapy crawl apkmirror-scraper`, the `/tmp/apkmirror_test` directory looks like this:

```
.
├── files
└── images
    └── full
        └── 5b3da62a528963315dd0b608528a04adb061a592.jpg
```

So although the image has been downloaded, the APK file hasn't.

Why does Scrapy's `FilePipeline` not work in this case? And how might I go about downloading the file?

Comment: Can you show an example of the scraped items? Also the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really enough for a proper answer, but I can't comment, so...

Things I would check:

1. You are using Tor Browser and say when you click the download button it gives you a download choice box. For me on chrome, it opens "https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-12-19-56-release/youtube-12-19-56-android-apk-download/download/" (note the /download/ at the end) where you wait for a few seconds. Maybe try scraping this?

   2. If what you mainly want is the download, you can try scraping through the elements of said /download/ page, or possibly even autogenerate the links yourself based on the post ID, for example:

We know that the class of the page is: `<body class="apps_post-template-default single single-apps_post postid-215041 single-author sidebar" role="document">`

And therefore the postid is `215041`.

So then we can use the link found on the download page `<a rel="nofollow" data-google-vignette="false" href="/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=215041">here</a>`

To steal it directly from `https://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=215041`

But... if we try this with another link, it fails, giving us 403 Forbidden. So likely there is something going on with a cookie or a referrer. I noticed _gid was the only cookie that changed, but that doesn't mean it's the culprit.

So maybe you will need some middleware for that.

Comment: I've tried downloading the page ending with `-android-apk-download/download/` using the `FilesPipeline`, but it downloads an HTML file and not the actual APK. I have managed to download the file using `urllib.urlretrieve` (equivalent to `urllib.request.urlretrieve` in Python 3) with a modified `User-Agent`, though.